# What happens if a motorcycle going at 50mph crashes head into a car going at 60mph?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, speed

I wonder if a motorcycle (going at 50mph) crashes into a car (going 60mph), what is the damage that motorcycle will experience?

Here's a diagram that shows what I've in mind:

```
[motorcycle -> 50mph] --> * <-- [60mph car]
```

Is the damage bigger for motorcycle if the situation was like this:

```
[motorcycle -> 50mph] --> [stand still car]
```

What about this:

```
[motorcycle standstill] <-- [60mph car]
```

Edit: Finally, what about this:

```
[motorcycle -> 110mph] --> [wall]
```

Comment: Please do not run the experiment.

Answer (score 1):

For the first three cases involving the car one can think of the collisions in the frame of reference where the motorcycle is at rest. The car approaches the motorcycle at a speed of 110 miles per hour in the first case, 50 miles per hour in the second case, and 60 miles per hour in the third. Comparing the three cases is a little easier now.

The force experienced by the motorcycle is equal to the change in its momentum; the details of the collision are not very apparent (e.g. whether or not it's an elastic collision) but we can assume that in each of the three cases the nature of the collision is similar. Then the momentum gained by the motorcycle will scale with the speed at which it is approached by the car, and consequently in the first case where it is approached by the car at 110 miles per hour is where the motorcycle will see the most damage.

Comparing the final case to the first three is not so easy since we would then need to know the details of the collision. If the wall hardly budges when hit by this motorcycle (this would be quite a sturdy wall) and the size of the car in consideration is comparable to the motorcycle, the motorcycle suffers more damage to the wall as its momentum is brought from $m*(110 mph)$ to zero. In the first case where it is approached by the car at 110 miles per hour the motorcycle begins with zero momentum but unless the mass of the car is remarkable compared to the motorcycle, its final momentum after collision will be far less than $m*(110 mph)$.

Answer (score 0):

> [motorcycle -> 110mph] --> [wall]

This is the worst case from all situations you mentioned. As the wall can neither move nor deform the force acting on the motorcycle can be calculated using the equality:

$mv^2/2 = F*d$, where $m$ is the mass of the motorcycle + man and $d$ is the distance traveled by the center of mass from the moment of impact till the motorcycle stops.

For $d = 1.5 m$, $m = 250 kg$, $v = 110 km/h$

$F = mv^2/2d=7.9 * 10^3 kgf$ which is about $8$ tonnes.